# How to take input from file in android espresso?

Tags: android-espresso

I am using **android espresso** for UI testing. For my huge project I need to take input from a file(csv, Excel ect.). How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use page object pattern.

If your test is:

```
onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(typeText("username"), closeSoftKeyboard())
onView(withId(R.id.pass)).perform(typeText("123456"), closeSoftKeyboard())
onView(withId(R.id.btnOk)).perform(click())
```

You can split in two files, Page Object file and Test file.

```
//PO file
var username = "user123"
var pass = "123456"
```

```
// Test file
onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(typeText(username), closeSoftKeyboard())
onView(withId(R.id.pass)).perform(typeText(pass), closeSoftKeyboard())
onView(withId(R.id.btnOk)).perform(click())
```

In P.O. file, you can implements everything you want.